# Type address in data source in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-connection, connection-string

I have some problem about type in connection string.

When I type my server address like this in C#:

```
string connection = "
Data source=./server ;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=sa;
Password=myPass
"
```

it doesn't work and doesn't find my server.

I checked my address in SQL Server Management Studio, and I saw it is `.\my server`

Yes it using ( `\` ) . not ( `/` ) .

But when I am trying to type ( `\` ) , it doesn't work in Visual Studio

I can't show my table :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a connection string as string literal in your C# code, you need to *either* duplicate the backslash:

```
string connection = "Data source=.\\myserver;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=sa;Password=myPass"
```

or you need to use a "here string" (the leading `@`) - then a single backslash will do:

```
string connection = @"Data source=.\myserver;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=sa;Password=myPass"
```

But yes - to separate machine name (`.`) from the instance name (`myserver`), SQL Server does in fact use backslash - not forward slash.

See loads of samples and explanations of all the various settings you can define in your connection strings at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)